# Debug status 500 Rails in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, heroku

Ruby `2.2.0`

Rails `4.1.4`

I get a 500 status code, but the reason is not indicated in logs.
When I click on a link, it immediately renders page 500.

Production on Heroku.

How can I find out the cause of error?

```
Started GET "/en/500" for myIP at 2019-09-26 11:37:03 +0000 
2019-09-26T11:37:04.013793+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SiteController#internal_server_error as HTML
```

In development mode, this error does not appear.

I tried `config.log_level = :debug`, `:info`, `:ERROR` and `config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` but nothing changed.

Comment: What _do_ the logs show @РоманОкс?

Comment: @SRack Nothing. I updated the question, look.

Comment: Guessing there's nothing before that in the logs? Any `before_actions` on the controller that could be throwing an error?

Comment: @SRack There is nothing in logs that could indicate an error. After clicking on link, 500 page is immediately rendered.

Comment: @spickermann I tried `config.log_level = :debug`, `:info`, `:ERROR` and `config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`

Comment: Wait a second. The log entry show that the request was `GET "/en/500"`. Why are you surprised to see that 500 error message when the browser obviously requested that exact page? Or did you request another URL? Which? Then there should be another log entry for that `GET` request.

Comment: @spickermann I request another url. In the routes I have `match "/500", to: "site#internal_server_error",: via =>: all` For some reason, a request for this url always gets to /500.

Comment: You might want to post your routes.rb. Perhaps you configured an optional path segment that might contain a locale?

Comment: @spickermann But in development mode, everything works. So it’s not about the routes?

Comment: You are saying that when you request `/500` or `/en/500` on development then you do not get a 500 status code page?

Comment: @spickermann The problem is that I cannot access the page on production server.
In development mode, I do not get /500 page when I click on the link.

Comment: @spickermann And again magic of rails occurred. I did nothing, I updated the page every 5 minutes, and it all worked! exde

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. Can you please tell what URL you actually requesting and how the log entry for that original request looks like before you get redirected to `/500`? Furthermore it might be helpful to have a look at the route and the contoller in question.

Comment: @spickermann I tried to follow the link to `/en/account/skills`, but I was immediately redirected to `/500`. Nothing happened in logs. Just an instant get request to `/500`. I think it was a problem with Heroku and I just had to wait.

Comment: @spickermann Thanks for trying to help me!